# RRAS not assigning DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, rras

I'm using RRAS as a VPN endpoint into our network. I have a static range setup for clients that connect and I can see the correct IP being assigned to a client, but the DNS server is set to 169.x.x.x on the client.

How can I get the connecting client to pickup the correct DNS server? At the moment the client fails to resolve domain names while connected to the VPN.

The NIC in the RRAS server has a static ip and has DNS servers assigned correctly. I'm only using 1 NIC for this, there is no internal/external NICs.

Answer (score 0):

169.x.x.x is an APIPA address and indicates that you have an IP conflict. Possibly the IP address you have assigned to the DNS server is the same with another existing IP on the network hence the conflict.

Since it is more difficult to change IP of the DNS server, try to locate the other IP that conflicts with the IP of your DNS server, change it to one available IP on your network and try to connect again.

It should resolve names properly after connecting to network using VPN.